# Is the memory freed when uninstall the windows driver?

Tags: windows, driver

If I allocate memory(ExAllocatePool) in my DriverEntry function and set Unload function, when the driver is unstalled, Is the memory I allocated freed automaticly as it is in a normal process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is never released.

The Windows kernel does not have a garbage collector and must be freed by the module that allocated it.